# `email.errors.InvalidHeaderDefect: addr-spec local part with no domain` error when building python package

Tags: python, github, build, package, pypi

I have a python package [here](https://github.com/PlaceReporter99/parspy) and the publishing workflow errors when building the package. The error is suggesting the email field in the pyproject.toml file is not formatted properly, but it is correct. Is the error coming from somewhere else? How do I fix it?

Comment: `pip install git+https://github.com/PlaceReporter99/parspy.git` works for me so everything seems to be ok.

Comment: @phd really? Ok.

Comment: @phd it installs but when i try to import it in the same virtual environment it says the module was not found.

Comment: It's a different question. Hint for the answer: you don't have any Python modules or importable packages in the source tree. Please read carefully https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: @phd do i need to wrap everything in a folder?

Comment: Depends if you want to install a single module or entire importable package(s) with directory/ies, `__init__.py` and submodule(s).

Comment: @phd there are no submodules apart from the builtin `re` module.

Comment: `re` is not your submodule, it's a module from standard library.

Comment: @phd oh........

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, it worked when I copied the toml file from the [packaging tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and edited the fields to match the project.